# Move all even files to different directory | Powershell and regex

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to move all even files from the current location to the directory "foo", but I have a problem matching them with regex.

Filenames are in this format:
11.txt, 121.txt, 342.txt

The command I'm currently using is:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^[0-9]*[02468]$'} | Move-Item -Destination .\foo
```

The previous command I was using works OK but only for two-digit files 1.txt-99.txt

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^[0-9]+[02468]'} | Move-Item -Destination .\foo
```

I tried at https://regex101.com/ site with .NET flavor and checked this regex `^[0-9]*[02468]$` and it works OK - matches all even numbers, but for some reason, I have a problem with above mention PS command...

Comment: you need to use  `.BaseName` to exclude the files extension otherwise the regex wouldn't work... `$_.BaseName -match '^\d*[02468]$'`

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method I have used previously for odds/evens is a division method. The solution Santiago has provided in the comments is also a valid regex method for this problem.

```
# Gets files and starts loop on files
Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp\AllFiles" -File | ForEach-Object {
    # If the BaseName of file is divisible by 2, else
    If($_.BaseName % 2 -eq 0) { 
        Move-Item -Destination "C:\Temp\Evens" -Path $_.FullName
    } Else { 
        Move-Item -Destination "C:\Temp\Odds" -Path $_.FullName
    }
}
```